# Failed hibernate mapping: An association from the table X refers to an unmapped class Y

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, pojo, hbm

Hi I'm trying to map this pojo Rent class to create his hibernate mapping file .

**Rent.java (POJO):**

```
  public class Rent implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       Employee employee;
       Client client;
       Car car;

    /* + getter and setter... */
  }
```

My intention is to create web-application where the user can set which employee have rented a car to a client.So this is the implementation i've tried

**Rent.hbm.xml** :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.google.musicstore.domain.Rent" table="RENT">
    <id name="id" column="RENT_ID">
       <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="car"  class="com.project.domain.Car"
       cascade="save-update">
    </one-to-one>
    <one-to-one name="client"  class="com.project.domain.Client"
       cascade="save-update">
    </one-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="employee"  class="com.project.domain.Employee"
       cascade="save-update">
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But it gives me this error:

```
   [java] Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table RENT refers to an unmapped class: com.project.domain.Employee
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you for the help.

I've also mapped all the entities in the **hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
    <mapping resource="com/project/carRentalAgency/domain/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/project/carRentalAgency/domain/Client.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/project/carRentalAgency/domain/Car.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/project/carRentalAgency/domain/Rent.hbm.xml"/>
```

[EDIT] As request i've added the files
**Employee.hbm.xml**

```
   <hibernate-mapping>
       <class name="com.project.carRentalAgency.domain.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
            <id name="id" type="long" access="field">
                <column name="ID" />
                <generator class="increment" />
            </id>
            <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
                <column name="EMPLOYEE_NAME" />
           </property>
           <property name="surname" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="EMPLOYEE_SURNAME" />
           </property>
           <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="EMPLOYEE_USERNAME" />
           </property>
           <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD" />
           </property>

      </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of:

(1) Your *class name* in `Employee.hbm.xml` is not a fully qualified class name

(2) You didn't declare all mapping resource in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

You might need to provide more information such as `Employee.hbm.xml` and `hibernate.cfg.xml` in addition to `Rent.hbm.xml` for us to check.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've just edited the post adding the files..
What you mean with the (1) "is not a fully qualified class name"? 
For the (2) i've declared the mapping resource of Employee, Client ,Car and Rent...so all the resource

Comment: In Rent.hbm.xml, your path is "com.google.musicstore.domain.Rent" while in hibernate.cfg.xml it's "com/project/carRentalAgency/domain/Rent.hbm.xml", might this inconsistency be an issue, right?

Answer (score 12):

I've found that usually this error occurred because the Build Action for the hibernate file classname.hbm.xml properties is not set to Embedded Resource.